# Monitoring a sub-process / can I get TotalProcessorTime for a Process group?

Tags: c#, windows, process, worker-processes

Is there a way to get the **Process.TotalProcessorTime** that reflects a process *PLUS* any processes that it has spawned?

Alternatively, how can I verify that the process (or it's descendants) are still "actively" running?

---

My app is spawning an external process and waiting for it to exit.  With sample data it takes 5-20 *minutes* to complete; I don't have a guess for a reasonable maximum timeout.  So my app checks the **Process.TotalProcessorTime** value on the other process at intervals, to ensure that it keeps rising.

This works fine, but I've discovered that the process is simply a "wrapper" that spawns a sub-process, which in turn spawns a handful of other sub-process that consume all of the CPU time.

And I've found that **TotalProcessorTime** returns only a small fraction of a second after several minutes of 100% CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't implemented this, but have figured out how it might work.  It's tedious but not all that complicated.

1. Spawn a background thread that every few seconds will:

   - Build the process tree (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138625/how-to-terminate-all-grandchild-processes-using-c-on-wxp-and-newer-mswindows/1138950#1138950) for a simplified version of the code),
   - Terminate (the monitor thread) if the process has exited.
   - Maintain a hash of the accumulated CPU Usage by PID,
   - Maintain a sum of all values by all processes,
   - Maintain the difference of the sum from the last time the thread fired.
2. This should allow the calling code to easily check that the process (tree) is
   not hung (*I/O bound processes might have problems here, but that doesn't apply 
   to my case*).

None of this seems difficult, with the possible exception of getting CPU usage of a process not spawned (directly) by the monitoring thread.

I'll update this answer if/when I implement the code, but it may be a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a performance counter to retrieve the parent process like this:

```
PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", 
    "Creating Process Id", " windbg");
Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pc.RawValue);
```

Having that information you can monitor processes in the system, maintain a structure of the whole process tree and calculate TotalProcessorTime for tree. Hope that helps