# How to find 64 bit process using process Id on ManagementObject (C#)

Tags: c#

I found some solutions to the kill child process by C# code ([How to terminate all [grand]child processes using C# on WXP (and newer MSWindows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138625/how-to-terminate-all-grandchild-processes-using-c-sharp-on-wxp-and-newer-mswi))

ManagementBaseObject m in new ManagementObjectSearcher("select ProcessId from Win32_Process where ParentProcessId=" + parentPid).Get()

In above query they get the process of Win32 but I need to know, how to get 64bit process using Management Object (C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use just WMI to find out is process 32 or 64 bit, but you can use process ID that you obtain via WMI and then call windows api IsWow64Process.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr process, [Out] out bool wow64Process);

private static bool IsWin64Emulator(this Process process)
{
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5 || (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1))
    {
        bool retVal;

        return IsWow64Process(process.Handle, out retVal) && retVal;
    }

    return false; // not on 64-bit Windows Emulator
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from win32_process");
    var processList = searcher.Get();

    foreach (var obj in processList)
    {
        var pid = int.Parse(obj["Handle"].ToString());
        var name = obj["Name"].ToString();
        var description = obj["Description"].ToString();

        try
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
            bool? is64bit = null;

            try
            {
                is64bit = process.IsWin64Emulator();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Cannot determine is {pid} process 64/32 bit ({exception.Message})");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"pid: {pid}, is64bit: {(is64bit.HasValue ? is64bit.Value.ToString() : "cannot determine")}, name: {name}, description: {description}");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Cannot get process by id {pid} ({exception.Message})");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for information, whether (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from win32_process");) this query used to get both 32 and 64 process?

Comment: Yes, both of 64 and 32 bit processes will be returned from WMI.